# Read an LP/MPS file in the PuLP

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, solver, python, pulp

I was trying to read a `MPS` file by using the `PuLP` package in the Python, but I can't find any related documents on it. Does anybody know, is there any way to read an LP/MPS file on the `PuLP`?

Comment: Check out the Q&A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43400679) as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to PuLP's [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/main/amply.html#Amply.load_file), it seems that `load_file` function in PuLP's `Amply` class can only handle AMPL files with a subset of AMPL syntax for data.

So if you want to use those LP/MPS files in `PuLP`, you may have to first convert them into AMPL files. You can either write a small script by yourself or use some existing scripts.

Here are some discussions ([post 1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ampl/5Q0NEALTBe4), [post 2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ampl/R6g4oT6IdyI)) in AMPL users group on how to do that or whether it is a good idea.